# How to use two sqlite database files in single iOS project with simultaneously fetch data from both Database

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

My requirement is to add two `SQLite` database files in my project. I know that is possible. But how can I access two database files simultaneously?

One more thing currently I am using `FMDB` to manipulate database operation.

**Note :** Both of my DB file sizes are near about `1GB` each. so also want to know that if I use 2 DB file so is there any memory issue will occur in my application ?

Thanks.

Comment: it's possible but you are your side set this database use this query that your database file path correct arrange.

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30638750/how-to-join-two-tables-from-two-different-databases-in-fmdb-in-a-ios-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, there is rare requirement of 2 Database files in a single project specially in iOS where we have used only one DB.

But as per your requirement, we can use multiple Database files in a single project with multiple Database instances.

**To Create 2 instance use below code for SQLite Native:**

```
//Create Object of DataBase
static sqlite3 *databaseOne = nil;
static sqlite3 *databaseTwo = nil;

//Open Both Databases while we needed in our project 

//Open First Database
sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &databaseOne);

//Opne Second Database
sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &databaseTwo);

//prepare for statement execution

sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseOne, [sql UTF8String], -1, &stmt, NULL)

sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseTwo, [sql UTF8String], -1, &stmt, NULL)
```

But make sure you will not mix these 2 objects while executing.

**Note:** Close both connections while your DB task is done.

**To Create 2 instance with FMDB use below code:**

```
//First DB
FMDatabase *dbOne = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:<your first DB file Path>];
[dbOne open];
//Do Your DB task
[dbOne close];

//Second DB 
FMDatabase *dbTwo = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:<your second DB file Path>];
[dbTwo open];
//Do Your Second DB task
[dbTwo close];
```

Hope this will help you.